# There's cit, dit, yit (change, delete, yank inside tag) on vim... is there something like pit (paste inside tag?)

Tags: vim

Using vim I'm used to motion command like `cit`, `dit`, `yit` when editing html/xml files. I like `.` even more after using this commands because I can repeat what I did with just one keystroke.

I would like to know if theres something like pit (paste inside tag) already available, that deletes inside the tag and paste what I wanted (from + register for example) and make `.` available like `cit`, or if I'll need to create a mapping for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, but you can select visually and put your text:

```
vitp
```

Comment: Hum, I knew the answer was obvious! And if is from the + register, just do `vit"+p`. `.` to repeat doesn't work though like cit...

Comment: Yes, in this case it might be easier to record a macro or map it to something and try a plugin like repeat.vim

Comment: Note that the replaced text ends up in the unnamed register, too, so if you want to do it mulitple times you need to either stuff your yank into a named register or use `"0` after the first paste.

Answer (score 1):

The excellent [vim-ReplaceWithRegister](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-ReplaceWithRegister) by Ingo Karat is most likely what you are looking for.

It defines the `gr` object to enable pasting the vim way for any motion:

```
USAGE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [count]["x]gr{motion}   Replace {motion} text with the contents of register x.
                            Especially when using the unnamed register, this is
                            quicker than "_d{motion}P or "_c{motion}<C-R>"
    [count]["x]grr          Replace [count] lines with the contents of register x.
                            To replace from the cursor position to the end of the
                            line use ["x]gr$
    {Visual}["x]gr          Replace the selection with the contents of register x.
```

Example, say you have to following buffer with tags with cursor at the first line:

```
<mytag> aaa </mytag>
<mytag> bbb </mytag>
<mytag> ccc </mytag>
```

`yit` yanks `aaa` into the unnamed register `""` as usual.
But if you go down to the next line (`j`), you can now replace with `grit` (paste in tag) the vim way, without overwriting the `""`.
Therefore, if you repeat `grit` on the 3rd line, you'll also replace `ccc` with `aaa`. Of course, just hitting `.` to repeat the last operation makes this even quicker.

It also plays nicely with the `global` command, i.e. after yanking, you could just `:%g/mytag/norm grit` to replace apply it on all line containing `mytag`.