# Vim: Have a paste operator (similar to c, d or y)

Tags: vim

I'd like to have an operator-pending mapping for paste that works in a way similar to how <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> work.

Something so that I can do <kbd>pi"</kbd> which would mean "paste inside quotes".

Is there already a plugin for this or would I have to make one?  If there isn't I'll make it, but I was curious in case I could save myself some work. :)

Of course I would make it using [Kana's vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) if I do make it myself.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6768930/1622940) but looking for a different answer. :)

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to that question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pasting inside delimiters without using visual selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126784/pasting-inside-delimiters-without-using-visual-selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.